# Python Pandas. Заменить в столбце одни значения на другие

Tags: python, pandas

Задача следующая есть столбец `BasePay1` в нём указанны числа, но и встречаются следующие значения: `Not Provided` . Так вот, мне необходимо данный признак преобразовать в тип `float64`.
Я делаю следующее: `df['BasePay'].astype('float64')`
И мне выходит ошибка: `could not convert string to float: 'Not Provided'`
По понятным вполне причинам)
Тип признака `BasePay` `object`
Вопрос как мне в признаке `BasePay` значения которые равны `Not provided` заменить например на 0.00 ? Это основной вопрос) Я и функции пытался писать, ничего не помогает. Понимаю что задача вполне лёгкая, но топчусь уже на одном мести часа 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью метода [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) заменить `'Not Provided'` на `NaN`, например.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 5.0, 'Not Provided'], ['Not Provided', 0.2, 3.3]])

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
              0    1             2
0           0.1  5.0  Not Provided
1  Not Provided  0.2           3.3

In [7]: df.dtypes
Out[7]: 
0     object
1    float64
2     object
dtype: object

In [8]: result = df.replace('Not Provided', np.nan)

In [9]: result
Out[9]: 
     0    1    2
0  0.1  5.0  NaN
1  NaN  0.2  3.3

In [10]: result.dtypes
Out[10]: 
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал вот так ```df['BasePay'] = df['BasePay'].replace('Not Provided', 0.00)``` и всё сработало!